# Drawing image in listview

Tags: c#, listview, picturebox

I'm trying to make this catalog app that display images with its "title" and "category" but I can't seem to display the image because of an error
on the line that says

```
images.Images.Add(row["id"].ToString(), new Bitmap(image_stream));
```

This is the whole of my code. I need the solution so i can print the image with its corresponding details in a list view. Thank you.

```
 namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                comboBox1.Items.Add("Books");
                comboBox1.Items.Add("Games");
                comboBox1.Items.Add("Music");
            }

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-4T5BLQ6\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CatalogDB;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlDataReader dataReader;
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            MemoryStream stream1;
            byte[] photo_array;

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                connection.Open();
                int i = 0;

                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                command.CommandText = "insert into EntryTable(Title,Category,Image) values('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + comboBox1.Text + "','" + pictureBox1.Image + "')";
                pictureBox1.Image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                byte[] pic = stream.ToArray();

                if (i > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Saved new item in index" + i);
                }

                connection.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Made New Entry");
                showData();
                clear();
            }

            void clear()
            {
                textBox1.Clear();
                pictureBox1.Image = null;
                comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
            }

            private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
                ofd.Filter = "Images only. |*.jpg; *jpeg; *.png; *.gif; *.bmp;";
                DialogResult result = ofd.ShowDialog();
                if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(ofd.FileName);
                }
            }
            private void showData()
            {
                connection.Open();
                listView1.Clear();
                ImageList images = new ImageList();
                images.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;
                listView1.LargeImageList = images;
                listView1.LargeImageList.ImageSize = new System.Drawing.Size(100 , 100);
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM EntryTable";
                dataAdapter.SelectCommand = command;
                dataTable.Clear();
                dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
                foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
                {
                    var image_buffer = (byte[])(row["Image"]);
                    MemoryStream image_stream = new MemoryStream(image_buffer, true);
                    image_stream.Write(image_buffer, 0, image_buffer.Length);
                    images.Images.Add(row["id"].ToString(), new Bitmap(image_stream));
                    image_stream.Close();
                    ListViewItem listItem = new ListViewItem();
                    listItem.Text = row["Title"].ToString();
                    listItem.ImageKey = row["Image"].ToString();
                    listView1.Items.Add(listItem);
                    listView1.Items.Add(row["Category"].ToString());
                    listView1.Items.Add(row["Title"].ToString());

                }



                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is likely that image_stream is null at that time. If you look at the ImageList.Add method signature it says it will Exception on null arguments. You should wrap that statement in a try catch block. My guess is that the image is coming back null from the database.

Comment: How do I do that? :)

Comment: In  what format you are storing it in DB? Image or bytes?

Comment: I store them in bytes

Comment: _because of an error on the line that says_ So, what does the error say???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xoriel,

You need to be more specific about what you are asking on SO. Your original post only indicates that you have and error and that it is holding up your app development (welcome to coding). You don't even tell us what error you are getting.

Now you ask how to implement a try catch? You should do a bit of research on your own. As far as try catch, you can start [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx).

Your code indicates a lack of understanding about how windows winforms are instantiated and their sequence of events. To me, this indicates that you will have further problems after this one is fixed, so I will add a try catch to your code. It will write the exception to your console.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
  {
    var image_buffer = (byte[])(row["Image"]);
    MemoryStream image_stream = new MemoryStream(image_buffer, true);
    image_stream.Write(image_buffer, 0, image_buffer.Length);
    try 
    {
        images.Images.Add(row["id"].ToString(), new Bitmap(image_stream));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    image_stream.Close();
    ListViewItem listItem = new ListViewItem();
    listItem.Text = row["Title"].ToString();
    listItem.ImageKey = row["Image"].ToString();
    listView1.Items.Add(listItem);
    listView1.Items.Add(row["Category"].ToString());
    listView1.Items.Add(row["Title"].ToString());
    }
```

Your true issue is the format in which you are storing the image to the database and the way in which you are retrieving it.

Regards,

Marc

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I am dabbling with windows forms atm. Forgive my ignorance.

Comment: ignorance is easy to remedy, stupidity is much more difficult... I wish you luck in your learning.